# Why did I get -2?

Tags: support, reputation

I just notice a weird behavior in the reputations:

[image]

Why did I get -2 after deleting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958409/how-to-fix-error-java-bean-started-with-null-constructor)?

Comment: ¡¿Is this your first -2?!

Comment: @brasofilo No, but this was unclear for me.

Comment: Well, I meant first from a removed post... [tag:status-bydesign]